# Residual symmetry group of a scalar field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, group-theory, higgs, symmetry-breaking

Given a Lagrangian

$$\frac{1}{2} (\partial_\mu \phi)^2 - \frac{\lambda}{4!}(\phi^2 - v^2)^2$$

for a real scalar field theory with $\vec{\phi} = (\phi_1,\phi_2,...,\phi_n)^T$ and $O(n)$ symmetry. Why is the residual symmetry group (or *little group*) given by $O(n\!-\!1)$ when spontaneous symmetry is broken?

Comment: Little group? Where is your vector? What leaves it invariant? How? Why? Show your work. Nobody is going to throw a pretty story at you which makes sense, unless you specify your language and what troubles you. This is routine stuff explained in most good texts.

Comment: @CosmasZachos actually that's part of my confusion as well (I found this statements in my lecture notes). The vector in this case would be the vector with compoenents $\phi_a$ where $a = 1,2,3,...,N$. As far I understand, the vacuum state here of the theory would coincide with the minimum of the potential so when $\phi_a \cdot \phi_a = v^2$.

Comment: So the rotations would belong to $O(n)$ the n-dimensional group of rotations. What I'm after is finding is to show that vacuum states given by the field $\phi$ (which must obey the condition in my previous comment) has $O(n-1)$ as the largest group that when acted upon leaves the state vector invariant.

Comment: My understanding was that we have a continuum of vacuum states  so we can choose one arbitrarily. Then I would find the largest subgroup of O(n) that leaves this state invariant and this should hold for the other vectors (as essentially all vacuum states are the "same"). Looking around I found that a similar statement is stated in "Gauge Theories of the Strong, Weak,and Electromagnetic Interactions" on page 90 (problem 5.6). 
I'm not sure what more details you think I should provide.

Comment: $\uparrow$ Is $N=n$?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo

Comment: @mathripper A different way to view things: The space of vacuum configurations is $S^{n-1}$ (i.e. you can place two $S^{n-1}$'s at the minima in the $O(n)$ model and this corresponds to orthonormal vectors $\sigma^{a}\sigma^{a} = 1$ that comprise the non-linear sigma model once you decouple $\lambda$ under limit $\lambda\to \infty$. Now there still exists a freedom to rotate the hyperplane orthogonal to $\sigma^{a}$ and hence, the symmetry reduces to $O(n-1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*O(n)* means you may rotate any *n*-vector to any other of the same length, or a suitably normalized combination of others. So you make a choice to rotate your reference vector to say, $\phi_1=v(1,0,0,..,0)^T$.

Its little group rotating the *n-1* components indexed by 2,3,...,*n* among themselves is thus *O(n-1)*, and it has the obvious $(n-1)(n-2)/2$ generators of that group acting linearly on your fields. The ones you "lost" (not really, the symmetry generators are still there, transforming $\phi_1$ to the other components, in a nonlinear manner) are the
$n-1$ ones realized nonlinearly, corresponding to massless Goldstone bosons (show this!). Your Goldstone bosons are $\phi_a$ with *a=2,3,...,n-1*, while $\phi_1$ is massive, the σ or Higgs.

Specifically,
$$
  \Delta_{ij}\phi_k= -\Delta_{ji}\phi_k= \theta_{ij}(\delta_{ik}\phi_i - \delta_{jk}\phi_j),
$$
So
$$
  \Delta_{ij}\phi_1= 0  
$$
For the *O(n-1)* *Δ*s involving only indices 2,3,...*n*.
Further,
$$
  \Delta_{1j}\phi_1=  \theta_{1j}\phi_j,
$$
for only one index, *j* in that set: these do not leave your reference vector invariant. There are *n-1* of them and shift the $\phi_j$ s by a constant *when* you redefine $\phi'_1$ to have a vanishing  vacuum value.